# Italic and bold Latin, and Greek letters using custom unicode font in gnuplot to produce (e)ps or pdf

Tags: utf-8, fonts, gnuplot, postscript

I would like to create a postscript or pdf figure with enhanced notations, italic or bold Latin characters, and sometimes (regular) Greek characters. How to do that in general?

Let's say I [downloaded](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/cmu-sans-serif) [CMU Sans Serif](https://www.checkmyworking.com/cm-web-fonts/#sans), a font that has glyphs for all the strange characters I ever want to use. I converted them to pfa with an [online tool](https://convertio.co/ttf-pfa/) and copied the files to the path of working directory.

### Expectations

Let's say I'd like to produce the following notation somewhere. 
[image: The notations using a text editor renders properly]

---

### What I tried: original

I create a gnuplot script encoded in a utf-8 file (without BOM) with the content

```
set term postscript eps enhanced "CMUSansSerif" 15 fontfile add 'CMUSansSerif.pfa' fontfile add 'CMUSansSerif-Oblique.pfa' fontfile add 'CMUSansSerif-Bold.pfa'
set encoding utf8
set o "print.eps"

p x t "Label: {/CMUSansSerif-Bold important }{/CMUSansSerif-Oblique note}: ∫⟨α₂ + β²⟩ = äßű"
set o
```

and executed with the newest gnuplot, version 5.2.6.

### What I got

I used a vector graphics editor to open the eps file and relevant part looks like this:

[image: the legend of the function does not contain the Greek letters]

---

### What I also tried

According to [Ethan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56204736/1837006) I added `adobeglyphnames` to the termoptions. It made at least the letters available but other Unicode symbols are still unavailable. The result is:
[image: Result with adobeglyphnames]

---

## Question

What went wrong? How could I produce the desired output?

<sup>So many possibilities, where things can go wrong: Is the font not suitable for this task? Did I download a wrong version of it? Did the pfa converter do a bad job? Did I include the font files incorrectly? Was there something wrong with the `set encoding`? Do I use a bad vector graphics editor? Do I have wrong fonts installed and the vector graphics editor tries to use them?</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that the answer is that in general PostScript is the wrong tool for this. If it is at all possible for you to work with PDF output instead, I suggest you do that. It is even possible the resulting PDF file can be translated to a PostScript file by standard tools (e.g. pdf2ps).  That is likely to work if the non-ascii characters are limited to Greek and other relatively common symbols but I don't know how much of the full unicode tables are covered by those standard tools.

If you really need to produce PostScript with additional unicode characters directly from gnuplot, you can find full instructions and sample character encoding tables in the gnuplot distribution files:

```
.../term/PostScript/unicode_maps.README
.../term/PostScript/unicode_big.map
.../term/PostScript/unicode_small.map
```

I am not familiar with the online tool font conversion you used but probably it failed because it did not have, or at any rate did not use, suitable character encoding tables for the desired conversion.

===

One other thought. There are two ways that a *.pfa font can encode unicode characters that are common enough to have a name assigned by Adobe for use in PostScript.  (1) It may use generic names like uni0439 for Unicode code points. (2) It may use Adobe-specific names from the list here:
[agl-aglfn glyph list](https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/agl-aglfn/blob/master/glyphlist.txt)

When selecting PostScript output from gnuplot you can tell it which of these two conventions is used by the font you provide. The default is "noadobeglyphnames".

```
set term postscript {no}adobeglyphnames
```

==

**(recipe for using "set term pdfcairo")**

Font handling is unfortunately system-specific, so I cannot tell you how to install or configure fonts on all your target machines.  I will show you a procedure that works on a linux desktop that uses the fontconfig utilities for system font handling.

1. Create directory */home/share/fonts/CMUSans*
2. Add this directory to the search list in file */etc/fonts/local.conf*
3. Copy *.ttf files into this directory from the CMU Sans Serif zip archive you link to in your original query.  The system fontconfig system tools should now be able to find these fonts.  By inspection they self-report as "CMU Sans Serif"
4. in gnuplot (tested with version 5.2.6)
   `set term pdfcairo font "CMU Sans Serif,15"
   set output 'enhanced_utf8.pdf'
   load 'enhanced_utf8.dem'`
5. convert output pdf file to PostScript with the following command

   `pdf2ps enhanced_utf8.pdf enhanced_utf8.ps`

Screenshot of the result is shown below
[image]

Comment: With adobeglyphnames it is as good as it can be. The problem starts at the fact that CMU Sans Serif does not contain the required characters.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that CMU Sans Serif doesn't contain the UTF-8 characters you are asking for. Check the font with a font editor like [Birdfont](https://birdfont.org/). Although the webpage shows symbols you want to use, the font itself does not contain them. However, your browser may show symbols, but they are just fallback representations from other fonts.